# Ubuntu cannot detect a partition but Windows can detect it

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I currently have dual boot on an SSD. Earlier I had a dual boot on my HDD. One of the partitions in the HDD is now not accessible to me when I boot from Ubuntu on the SSD. It cannot detect the partition. However, when I boot Windows from the same SSD, it can still detect the HDD partition.

Output of lsblk

NAME  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

sdb       8:16   0  931.5G  0 disk
├─sdb4    8:20   0   937M  0 part
├─sdb10   8:26   0  11.5G  0 part
├─sdb2    8:18   0   128M  0 part
├─sdb9    8:25   0   460M  0 part
├─sdb7    8:23   0 269.5G  0 part
├─sdb5    8:21   0    73G  0 part
├─sdb11   8:27   0     1M  0 part
├─sdb3    8:19   0 216.9G  0 part /home
├─sdb1    8:17   0   650M  0 part
├─sdb8    8:24   0   350G  0 part
├─sdb6    8:22   0   7.5G  0 part
└─sdb12   8:28   0   1.1G  0 part
sda       8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk
├─sda4    8:4    0   509M  0 part
├─sda2    8:2    0    16M  0 part
├─sda7    8:7    0   7.7G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda5    8:5    0  78.1G  0 part
├─sda3    8:3    0  99.9G  0 part
├─sda1    8:1    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda6    8:6    0  37.3G  0 part /

Comment: Please post the output of `lsblk`.

Comment: Was Ubuntu OS installed on the HDD? And assuming the SSD is a new addition, did you perform a new Ubuntu OS installation on the SSD?

Comment: @darth_epoxy Yes, Initially Ubuntu OS was installed on HDD. The SSD is a new addition. Now, new Ubuntu OS is installed on the SSD.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi added the output. The partition referred here is sdb8

Comment: If you cannot mount it manually, try running `gparted` and check the permissions on that drive / partition. BE CAREFUL this tool does not ask twice so don't go formatting or deleting anything!

Comment: @darth_epoxy how to check the permissions on that drive. I opened the gparted but cannot find permissions option.

Comment: Ah sorry, you have to go to View then File System Support. but ... now that I do this myself it appears you are right and it will not actually change them, just display them. If it has read and wrote permissions, then you just need to figure out how to mount it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141727/discussion-between-interval-and-darth-epoxy).